# Pairwise trend comparisons for a joint model

Tags: mixed-model, survival, multiple-comparisons, marginal-model, joint-modeling

I have built a joint model for longitudinal and survival data using the jointModel function in JM. I would like to perform pairwise comparisons of three trends of the longitudinal outcome of the joint model. Is there a way to do this? Would I have to resort to creating separate models and adjusting for multiple comparisons?